# Example where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n)^4$ does not

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came up with $a_n=(-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$. Just wanted to check if it works.Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't quite work but you are on the right track.

Comment: sorry, make that $a_n=(-1)^n/n^{1/4}$

Comment: Both sums are convergent, but you only need to tweak $a_n$ so that $(a_n)^4$ remains large enough.

Comment: That comment should work.